# mediawiki deleted namespaces and pseudo ones

Tags: namespaces, mediawiki

here my Problem:

I have a few sites with "pseudo" namespaces, e.g. "8800:Site" - but 8800 isnt a Namespace.
But most of my sites have real namespaces, e.g. "NG:Site".

When i remove all namespaces out of my Localsettings.php, in my thoughts "NG" is a pseudo Namespace too - not declared anywhere.

But:

Internal Links (even if i type it direct in browser) to Sites in "NG" namespaces didnt work anymore (with and without "NG:") - 8800 sites do.

Can someone explain that to me?
What happens with Sites which namespaces are deleted?
And what is my fallacy about "if i delete Namespace NG it should be "pseudo" like 8800"?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to fix up all pages on the wiki when you delete or change namespaces in a way that may affect existing pages -- otherwise the wiki can no longer "see" those pages. This is because titles in the database are stored as (namespace id, remaining title text) pairs. So some "OldNS:Title" would have gotten stored as something like (104, "Title") ... now that you've removed it, when the wiki goes looking for something called "OldNS:Title" it gets parsed into (0, "OldNS:Title") and there's no match between the two.

There is a maintenance script to fix up these problems; for some cases [namespaceDupes.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aNamespaceDupes.php) works and is faster, for this case you may need to run [cleanupTitles.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aCleanupTitles.php) which is more thorough but slower.